# Creating a sub dataframe from a dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to create a data frame that only includes av_rating for the title - "Law & Order: Special Victims Unit" from the following CSV file. How can I do that? The following code is giving me the same data as subset instead of just giving only for the title "Law & Order: Special Victims Unit"

```
import pandas as pd
ratings = pd.read_csv("http://becomingvisual.com/python4data/tv.csv")
ratings
subset = ratings[["title", "av_rating"]]
subset
for i in subset["title"]:
  if i == "Law & Order: Special Victims Unit":  
    subset_1 = subset[["title", "av_rating"]]
subset_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JGM answers the OP's question (with a small change).  Filter is to be on title column rather than on av_rating column.

```py
ratings[ratings['title'] == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit'][['title','av_rating']]
```

and `.loc` method also can be used to filter.

```py
ratings.loc[ratings['title'] == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit',  ['title','av_rating'] ]
```

`ratings['title'] == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit'` is a index filter

`['title','av_rating']` is a columns selector

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a filter like this:

```
filter = ratings.av_rating == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit'
```

The filter is a boolean variable, and return something like:

```
filter = [True, True, False, True, ... , True, False]
```

**True** occures when ratings.av_rating == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit' and **False** occures when ratings.av_rating != 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit', naturally.

Then, you need to use the filter, to select the values that you want:

```
final_data = rating[filter]
```

The variable final_data contains the old data ONLY when filtre == True (ratings.av_rating == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit'). Now, to select only title and av_rating:

```
final_data_titles = final_data[["title", "av_rating"]]
```

You can use **query** too:

```
final_rating = rating.query("av_rating == 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit'")
```

Then,

```
final_data_titles = final_data[["title", "av_rating"]]
```